# Twilio local sync not working in Android Client Error code 6 and Error message Storage service is temporarily unavailable

Tags: android, twilio, offlineapps

I integrated twilio ipmessaging on Android.It is working fine when I am online but When I try to send message when device is offline it is giving error like **Storage service is temporarily unavailable**.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, offline mode communication is not currently supported.

You could implement it in your own app though, we are going to expose connection status indication to your app soon from the SDK.

Comment: Thank you. But In quickstart project (which is mentioned in twilio website)it  is defaulty working when mobile goes offline. Is it implemented in that app. Can you tell me How can I do that or where could I get reference for that.

Comment: It just reconnects after mobile is woken up. Can you provide link to specific documentation where you read that?

Comment: k.Might be I am mistaken.I have seen sync option in features page. Is it the upcoming feature of twilio sdk ? Can you tell me or give reference link on how to implement local sync feature. Thank you.

Comment: Sync option is something entirely different, it specifies amount of data to sync on init - do we take a short amount of channel data from service or full channel state.